# Collection panel

Tags: interface

While working at Blender, I accidentally closed the Collections Panel. Unfortunately, research didn't helped me find a way to return it, I hope you can help me.
How to open Collections panel?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell from your question, but what you're calling “the Collections Panel” is probably the [Outliner](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/editors/outliner/introduction.html) editor area.  Either switch the [Editor Type](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/editors/index.html) of one of the open areas (upper left corner) to Outliner, or [open a new area](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/interface/window_system/areas.html) and switch its Editor Type to Outliner.

[image]

This answer is for Blender 3.0 (the current version), and may be different if you're using something else.